# Counting duplicate random numbers from a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a score predictor based on a teams goal difference (football). I am new to JavaScript, and I have managed to get this far.

I want it to be like spinning a ten-sided dice 20 times + the team's goal difference. I have got this bit sorted I think.  With my code now I have a list of random numbers logged in the console which is what I wanted.  Now I would like to choose a number (e.g., 2) and see how many times this occurs in the list. I'd like to save this in a new variable called homeFinalScore (So if '2' occurs three times in the list of random numbers, the homeFinalScore variable should be 3). I've tried several things but have been unable to sort it yet!

Any help would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance!

```
 var homeFinalScore = 0;

        function calculateScore(){
            var homeTeam = document.getElementById("HomeTeam").value;
            var awayTeam = document.getElementById("AwayTeam").value;
            var homeGd = parseInt(document.getElementById("HomeGD").value);
            var awayGd = parseInt(document.getElementById("AwayGD").value);

            var homeGd = 20 + homeGd;
            var awayGd = 15 + awayGd;

            for (i = 0; i < homeGd; i++) {
                var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11); 
                console.log(randNum);
            }
  }
```

Comment: _"Now I would like to choose a number (eg: 2) and see how many times this occurs in the list"_ What is "list"? Are you trying to determine a specific value occurs within `randNum` value? Or, create an array of `randNum` values, then determine how many occurrences of a specific value are present within array?

Comment: I'm trying to determine how many times a certain number occurs when [randNum] is passed through the loop, if that makes sense

Comment: the latter. I think an array might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array, use `Array.prototype.push()` to push `randNum` to the array, then use `Array.prototype.filter()`, `.length` to determine how many occurrences of a value are present within array.

```js
var homeGd = 20 + 2;
var awayGd = 15 + 2;
var arr = [];

function countOccurrences(n, arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(value) {
    return value === n
  }).length;
}

for (i = 0; i < homeGd; i++) {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  arr.push(randNum);
}

console.log(arr);

console.log(countOccurrences(2, arr));
```

Alternatively, you can increment a variable when `randNum` is equal to a value.

```js
var homeGd = 20 + 2;
var awayGd = 15 + 2;
var n = 0;
var num = 2;

for (i = 0; i < homeGd; i++) {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  console.log(randNum);
  if (randNum === num) {
    ++n
  }
}

console.log("occurrences of 2:", n);
```

Comment: Cheers. That has done what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help guest271314!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const homeGd = 10;
const randomNumbers = []; // array of random numbers

for (i = 0; i < homeGd; i++) {
    randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 11));
}
const countBy = randomNumbers.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current] = (acc[current] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(countBy);
```